# Creating array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, initialization

Is there any difference between

```
[1, "hi", []]
```

and

```
Array[1, "hi", []]
```

and

```
Array.[1, "hi", []]
```

If there is no difference (as `ri 'Array::[]'` suggests) why `Array[...]` and `Array.[...]` exist?

Comment: I made mistake in the third example `Array.[](1, "hi", [])` instead of `Array.[1, "hi", []]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last example would have to be written like:

```
Array.[](1, 'hi', [])
```

This last way of writing an array shows that `Array::[]` is just another method of the class `Array`. The method takes `x` splat arguments and creates/returns the new array.

The other ways of writing an array are just syntax sugar provided in Ruby for easy readability and convenience

Also, looking at the source code, we can see a new array is created and returned at the end:

```
               static VALUE
rb_ary_s_create(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE klass)
{
    VALUE ary = ary_new(klass, argc);
    if (argc > 0 && argv) {
        MEMCPY(RARRAY_PTR(ary), argv, VALUE, argc);
        ARY_SET_LEN(ary, argc);
    }

    return ary;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I thought that there must be some difference.

Comment: Array literals are *not* syntactic sugar for `Array::[]`. Try overriding `Array::[]` and see what happens when you use the literal syntax. Hint: nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

The first is an `Array` literal. Literals are built into the language specification, Ruby does not allow overriding, modifying, or otherwise changing or influencing the meaning of a literal.

The second is a method call. Ruby *does* allow modifying the behavior of methods, ergo, someone, somewhere could have changed the definition of `Array::[]` to do something different.

The third is a `SyntaxError`, so it is *very obviously* not equivalent to either of the other two.

Comment: Thank you. I made mistake in the third example.